# получить ссылки со всего сайта

Tags: python-3.x, парсер, beautiful-soup

Впервые открыл питон и впервые пишу парсер, используя Beautiful Soup хочу получить все ссылки со всего сайта, пока скрипт смотрит только одну страницу, как пойти дальше я не знаю.
Сейчас скрипт выглядит так:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib2 import urlopen

import io

html_doc = urlopen('http://site.ru').read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc)

# ищем div с нужным классом
collect = soup.find('body') 
# в найденном div'е, ищем все ссылки (т.е. теги a).
links = collect.findAll('a') 
links_array=[]
for link in links:
    links_array.append('http://site.ru'+link.get('href'))

f = io.open('parsed_data.htm', 'w', encoding='utf8')
i=0
#запишем в файл
while i < len(links_array):
    f.write(""+str(i)+"<a href='"+str(links_array[i]).decode('utf-8')+"'></a><br/>")
    i=i+1
f.close()
```

Comment: Это `'http://site.ru'+link.get('href')` будет работать пока в href находится относительный путь, а не к примеру: `http://old.site.ru/1111.html`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вы уверены, что ссылки на данном сайте находятся ТОЛЬКО в тэгах "а", то собрать ссылки со всех страниц сайта можно вот так:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib2 import urlopen
import io

pages_to_parse=['http://site.ru']
parsed_pages=[]
site_links=[]

while pages_to_parse != []:
    current_page = pages_to_parse.pop()
    html_doc = urlopen().read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc)
    # ищем div с нужным классом
    collect = soup.find('body') 
    # в найденном div'е, ищем все ссылки (т.е. теги a).
    a_tags_on_page = collect.findAll('a') 
    links_on_page = []
    for link in a_tags_on_page:
        links_on_page.append('http://site.ru'+link.get('href'))

    parsed_pages.append(current_page)
    for i in links_on_page:
        if i not in site_links:
            site_links.append(i)
        if i not in parsed_pages:
            pages_to_parse.append(i)
    links_on_page = []


f = io.open('parsed_data.htm', 'w', encoding='utf8')
i=0
#запишем в файл
while i < len(site_links):
    f.write(""+str(i)+"<a href='"+str(site_links[i]).decode('utf-8')+"'></a><br/>")
    i=i+1
f.close()
```

Comment: Пробую Ваш способ. выдает только одну ссылку.Вот такой лог:
C:/PycharmProjects/testby/ParserURL.py:16: UserWarning: No parser was explicitly specified, so I'm using the best available HTML parser for this system ("lxml"). This usually isn't a problem, but if you run this code on another system, or in a different virtual environment, it may use a different parser and behave differently. The code that caused this warning is on line 16 of the file C:.PycharmProjects/testby/ParserURL.py. To get rid of this warning, pass the additional argument 'features="lxml"' to the Beautifu

Comment: это не ошибка, просто вы не указали, какой парсер использовать, поэтому BeautifulSoup и сообщает, что возьмет по умолчанию lxml. В большинстве случаев это ни на что не влияет. А то, что собирается в итоге одна ссылка, тут надо смотреть на код и на разметку сайта. Я таким образом собирал ссылки много раз.